web scraping, etiqueta <a href
Este es mi primera pregunta en este foro. Soy novata en el web scraping y de vba tampoco tengo muchos conocimientos, estoy intentando acceder a la última línea que he pegado del código pero no hay manera. ¿Alguna idea?
<ul class="col">
<li class"sm"
   <li class="sm end"
      <a class="sm" href=XXX data-onclick=xxx data-unique-id=xx
     <ul class="sm">
        <li class="folder" role="menu" aria-checked="false>
          <div>Apertura</div>
         <ul>
             <li class="leaf" role="menu" aria-checked="false">...</li>
             <li class="leaf" role="menu" aria-checked="false">
                 <a href="XXX" data-onclick='[{"-nwbc-call":"parent.pro54_open_window","-nwbc-args":"BB"},{"-nwbc-call":"return_false"}]' data-unique-id="AA">PEDIDO</a>

Todos los bucles que les paso no me devuelve la etiqueta de PEDIDO que es la que me interesa. Este bucle, ya sea con getElementsByTagName o getElementsByClassName tanto en "li" como "ul", "div", "a", no me devuelve esa línea donde está la etiqueta de Pedido:
With IE.Document
   Set selectItem = .getElementsByTagName("li")
    For Each element In selectItem
          MsgBox element.innerText
    Next element
End With

Gracias y saludos,

Lo he cambiado por esto, pero me devuelve los nombres de los menús de la cinta superior y lateral. Al principio, en la primera línea Set... me da error el objeto no admite esta propiedad o método, pero le doy a continuar y ya sí traga pero lo dicho, no me da lo que yo quiero:
Al final me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:"navegador web está actualmente configurado de tal modo que no se visualizan marcos" ¿será por algo de esto?
With IE.Document
   Set selectItem = .querySelectorAll("li")
    For Each element In selectItem
          MsgBox element.innerText & " " & element.id
    Next element
End With


Con Javascript funciona:


const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
listItems.forEach( listItem => console.log(listItem.innerText))
<span>
  <ul>
    <li> texto </li>
    <li><a>texto en cursiva</a> </li>
  </ul>
</span>



Pero es posible que VBA use otra API, por lo que veo en esta otra P&R en inglés. Prueba con element.Text

Hola Pablo gracias, me sale error referencia no válida o sin calificar en .querySelectorAll y otra duda ¿no tendría que definir listItems como objeto?

Mi código sólo era un test para comprobar que innerText incluye texto de las etiquetas hijas, pero lo que te estaba sugiriendo era usar tu código simplemente cambiando innerText por Text, porque el API del DOM de VBA es distinto

Sugiero compartas la web y no olvides que Internet Explorer ya tiene fecha de fin para usarse en Windows 10 y Windows 11
